# Trying to make Cypress, TypeScript and IstanbulJS work together

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, istanbul, rollupjs

I am trying to generate code coverage reports with [IstanbulJS](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs) for my code written in [TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) and tested with [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). But things get reported out of place:

[image: IstanbulJS's HTML report with hit counter in the wrong lines]

I created a [git repository](https://github.com/papb/cy-ts-istanbul-question) [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) specifically for this question, so you can reproduce exactly my situation:

```
git clone https://github.com/papb/cy-ts-istanbul-question
cd cy-ts-istanbul-question
npm install
npm test
# And then open the file `coverage/index.ts.html` to see the image above.
```

**How to fix that?**

---

### Details

I have some code written in TypeScript which I transpile and bundle to a single JavaScript (ES6) file with [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/), [rollup-plugin-typescript2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-typescript2) and [rollup-plugin-istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-istanbul). This works perfectly, my source code in TypeScript becomes a file ready to be included with a `<script>` tag into the browser and used.

Secondly, I use [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) to run tests on an HTML page which includes the transpiled JS code mentioned above. This also works perfectly, cypress is able to test my functions originally written in TypeScript.

Now, I want to set up coverage reports for those tests. On Cypress FAQ we can find the question *[Is there code coverage?](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq.html#Is-there-code-coverage)* to which the answer is currently *no* (regarding built-in functionality) but is [in discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/346) as a welcome thing to be done in the future, and [in fact it can be done](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/346#issuecomment-415462938).

The thing is: the guy who did it above was not using TypeScript. I am. So I have a little extra step to do, and this is where I'm currently stuck. Intuitively, I think this is just a matter of configuring IstanbulJS to follow the source maps correctly, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do it. [Every guide about TypeScript + IstanbulJS that I can find](https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/typescript/) assumes that I am using Mocha, but I'm not - I am using Cypress with a transpiled source coming from TypeScript.

*Note: I am aware that in general the usual "code coverage" approach to cypress testing doesn't make much sense, but in my exact situation I think it does, I've thought about it already, please don't make this frame challenge to the question.*

---

**EDIT:** To be clear, using rollup here is not a hard requirement. If you have a solution that uses something else, it is totally acceptable as well. The important thing is, as title says, Cypress + TypeScript + IstanbulJS.

Comment: Have you really need to use `Cypress`? For a similar thing i used [Intern.js](https://theintern.io/) with some transpilation ES6 to ES5 with `Rollup` and code coverage worked like a charm

Comment: @Troopers Hello, thanks for the tip, I will take a look later. I wanted cypress to make interface testing, clicking on buttons, snapshot testing, etc. Exactly what cypress shines at. Can Intern.js do those as well?

Comment: [Functionnal testing](https://theintern.io/docs.html#Intern/3/docs/docs%2Ffunctional-testing.md/writing-a-functional-test) is supported. For snapshot i'm not sure

Comment: @Troopers Thanks. I will consider using it, but for now I am still looking for a solution in Cypress. Also, you said you used transpilation ES6 -> ES5, but how about TypeScript? Would it work?

Comment: Intern.js is writed in TypeScript and tested with Intern. So i think this works

Comment: Vue-cli can generate a config exactly like this. You should create a sample project and look at what they did

Comment: @SeanKelly - Are you sure it makes code coverage reports? Looks like they only use cypress + typescript, but not instanbuljs or nyc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used `webpack` + `babel-loader` + `@babel/preset-typescript` + `babel-plugin-istanbul`

basically the strategy is:

- instrument your app code so that coverage is generated on `window.__coverage__`
- after cypress spec runs, use `cy.writeFile` to save the report to `.nyc_output`
- and generate the report with `cy.exec('nyc report --reporter=html')`

**you should then be able the view the html coverage report in the `coverage/` directory**

Here's the changes I made to your project, switching to `webpack` with fully working code coverage:

https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-code-coverage/commit/40f88aa27778dc55ad3fae56af66724f73b6496d
[image]

I have put together other working examples [here](https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-code-coverage). It has examples of setting up code coverage on top of a newly ejected `create-react-app`(uses `webpack`) and a vanilla `typescript + webpack` project:

#### [create-react-app-ejected](https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-code-coverage/tree/master/examples/create-react-app-ejected):

cypress with code coverage set up on a newly-ejected [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)
**uses**:

- `@babel/preset-typescript`
- `@cypress/webpack-preprocessor`
- `babel-loader`
- `babel-plugin-istanbul`

#### [vanilla-typescript-webpack](https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-code-coverage/tree/master/examples/vanilla-typescript-webpack):

code coverage on a vanilla typescript & webpack project
**uses**:

- `@babel/preset-typescript`
- `@cypress/webpack-preprocessor`
- `babel-loader`
- `babel-plugin-istanbul`

[image]

In both of these I also instrument the cypress code so that you could possibly merge the coverage reports, but I don't do that currently

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much. Bounty well deserved. I have also opened a PR on your repo with a minor fix. In the near future I will be updating my own repo with your changes, adding them manually, in parts, so I fully understand what is going on. For now I only had the chance to run your code and see that it really works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to figure this out. It seems to be an issue with how rollup generates compatible code. I was able to get the branch up to 75% by changing your tsconfig target

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

It covers all the code, but there must be a branch generated by rollup that's getting passed. But I don't really think Cypress is intended for functional testing like this

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you very much for spending your time :) I am on my phone now, can't give a detailed look now, but will do later or perhaps tomorrow. By the way, if you think rollup is messing up, feel free to suggest a solution with something else. Rollup is not a hard requirement for this question, only TypeScript, IstanbulJS and Cypress are.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt once again, but this didn't really solve my issue. The coverage changed, but everything is still off in the coverage report: [see here](https://i.imgur.com/Y2YcsGE.png) the output I've got with your modifications.